# how to make a list of lists in to dictionary of tuples

Tags: python

I had **list of lists** for example

```
res = [[None,'A','B'],[19980228, 'd1', 't1'],[19980302, 'd2', 't2'],[19980303, 'd3', 't3']]
```

Now i need to frame the above result as **dictionary of list of tuples** like

```
{'A': [(19980228, 'd1'), (19980302, 'd2'), (19980303, 'd3')], 
 'B': [(19980228, 't1'), (19980302, 't2'), (19980303, 't3')]}
```

Please let this me know this concept, Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

this should do it:

```
x, A, B = res[0]
output = {A:[], B:[]}
for a,b,c in res[1:]:
  output[A].append((a, b))
  output[B].append((a, c))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> res = [[None,'A','B'],[19980228, 'd1', 't1'],[19980302, 'd2', 't2'],[19980303, 'd3', 't3']]
>>> {a:[(r[0], r[i]) for r in res[1:]] for i, a in enumerate(res[0]) if a}
{'A': [(19980228, 'd1'), (19980302, 'd2'), (19980303, 'd3')], 'B': [(19980228, 't1'), (19980302, 't2'), (19980303, 't3')]}
```

Note: as @shuzOMGchen points out, this requires "dictionary comprehensions" which were added in python 2.7 and 3.0, so if you are using an earlier version than you will have to change the code a bit.  Here it is without using a dict comprehension(it's pretty ugly, I just tried to copy my logic from above)

```
>>> res = [[None,'A','B'],[19980228, 'd1', 't1'],[19980302, 'd2', 't2'],[19980303, 'd3', 't3']]
>>> d = {}
>>> for i, a in enumerate(res[0]):
...     if a:
...         d[a] = [(r[0], r[i]) for r in res[1:]]
... 
>>> d
{'A': [(19980228, 'd1'), (19980302, 'd2'), (19980303, 'd3')], 'B': [(19980228, 't1'), (19980302, 't2'), (19980303, 't3')]}
```

Comment: how does it work?, wait I think I'm getting it .. thats really smart!

Comment: Please note that this technique takes advantage of "dictionary comprehensions", a feature that was added in python 2.7 and 3.0, so if you're pre-2.7 this will turn hairier.

Dictionary comprehensions are described in  http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/

Comment: @shuzOMGchen That's a good point, I'm so used to having them that I hadn't even thought about that.  I've edited a small warning into my post, thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> res = [[None,'A','B'],[19980228, 'd1', 't1'],[19980302, 'd2', 't2'],[19980303, 'd3', 't3']]
>>> d = dict((x[0],x[1:]) for x in zip(*res))
>>> nums = d.pop(None)
>>> for key in d:
        d[key] = zip(nums,d[key])


>>> d
{'A': [(19980228, 'd1'), (19980302, 'd2'), (19980303, 'd3')], 'B': [(19980228, 't1'), (19980302, 't2'), (19980303, 't3')]}
```